# maven versions plugin: How to update parent to specific version, not latest?

Tags: maven

Are there any ways to update parent to specific version using mvn?
I tried to use Versions plugin, but it updates to latest version.

E.g.:
I have parent versions 1.4 and 1.5.
I want child to use 1.4.

I tried:

```
mvn versions:update-parent
```

This updates parent version to 1.5 (latest).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you gave the exact command you tried and the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using it like this:

```
 mvn -f parent\pom.xml versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: This updates parent's pom.xml. I need to update child's pom.xml

Comment: Thanks @ptrk ! Now I figured out how it works! I forgot about [ ]